# How to resolve permission error in docker?

Tags: docker, apple-m1

docker version 4.21.1
device: macbook pro m1
Error:
[Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open '/usr/app/src/server.js'] {
errno: -1,
code: 'EPERM',
syscall: 'open',
path: '/usr/app/src/server.js'
}

Below are my dockerfile and docker compose file contents:

dockerfile:

```
FROM node:20-alpine3.17 as deps_installer

RUN mkdir -p /usr/app
WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

FROM node:20-alpine3.17 as deployment

WORKDIR /usr/app 

COPY --chown=node:node --from=deps_installer /usr/app/node_modules ./node_modules

COPY --chown=node:node ./src ./src
COPY --chown=node:node package.json .
COPY --chown=node:node nodemon.json .

USER node 

CMD [ "npm","run","dev" ]
```

compose file

```
version: "3"

volumes:
  pg_data:

networks:
  arg-network:

services:
  express-server:
    container_name: node-server
    image: arg-express-server
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: deployment
    networks:
      - arg-network
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/app/src
    ports:
      - 80:8000
    env_file:
      - .env

  postgres-server:
    container_name: postgres-db
    image: postgres:15.5-alpine3.19
    networks:
      - arg-network
    volumes:
      - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=arg-user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$#$SDFS^&%^343
      - POSTGRES_DB=arg
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

Answer (score 0):

The setup looks fine. It seems like there is a trouble in your file location in the host machine. Make sure the volumes you are mapping in docker compose exists or docker has permissions to access.